# Bootstrap pagination rendering extra 'pagination'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I'm using the native bootstrap.css and regular jquery to generate an ajax pagination. The output code is as follows (truncated, but all li's follow the same pattern):

```
<ul class="paginate">
  <li class="first active">1</li>
  <li><a href="#" data-page="2" title="Page 2">2</a></li>
  ......
</ul>
```

Output is expected as a regular pagination feature, but instead lists the boxes twice.

I can't post direct image due to rep -see here for example: http://cl.ly/image/0l3h2D3D1Z3X

According to Safari's Web Inspector, the leftmost sequence refers to the li's and the rightmost to the 'a' links -albeit only the left boxes are clickable.

Comment: Bootstrap uses `pagination` class for pagination, not `paginate`, see [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination). Seems like a conflict with other styles/libraries.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Great spot, I'd actually changed this earlier today and it fixes half the problem. For those reaching from Google, the bootstrap paginate treats non hyperlinked 'pages' differently, resulting in them rendering as plain text outside of the pagination.